# Which amiibo unlock content?

Tags: amiibo, super-mario-odyssey

I think I've seen somewhere that the Wedding Suit Mario amiibo unlocks Mario in a wedding dress.

Is this true? Do other amiibo unlock other outfits, or do anything besides giving hints?

Comment: I've gotten coins from my wii fit trainer amiibo

Comment: Googling around - it seems that whatever outfit amiibo you have can be used to unlock the corresponding outfit.  One I found funny was the Peach Wedding Outfit Amiibo unlocks the same outfit for Mario.

Comment: A good question title may be "What do Amiibo do in Super Mario Odyssey?"

Comment: Note that all outfits become available for purchase after you beat the game and collect enough moons. The amiibo will unlock them right away and for free, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.gamespot.com/gallery/super-mario-odyssey-amiibo-guide-what-each-figure-/2900-1565/

Also, [this wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Amiibo) has some additional info:

> Scanning the Mario, Dr. Mario, Luigi, Wario, Waluigi, Diddy Kong, Gold Mario, Wedding Mario, Wedding Peach, and Wedding Bowser amiibo through Uncle amiibo unlock these characters' outfits for Mario to wear. Uncle amiibo also recognizes a wide variety of Nintendo character amiibo, such as Daisy, Rosalina, Yoshi, Link, Samus and Toad by their official names.
>   While holding Right Button, scanning any Mario amiibo makes Mario temporarily invincible (as if he were under the effect of a Super Star), any Peach amiibo supplies a Life-Up Heart, and any Bowser amiibo (except Skylander Bowser) shows regional coin locations. Other amiibo give the player up to three coins or a Life Up Heart per scan, which can be done an unlimited number of times, reveal a Power Moon location, or unlock more costumes.

Comment: While it may answer the question, it would be good to add the relevant information into your answer in the event the video were to be taken down

Comment: Fair enough, added some more detail to the answer.

Comment: @Wondercricket As warned, the linked video has since been removed from YouTube.